# Rails: Accessing Nested Params in the Model Layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, parameters

I have a model that accepts nested params:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :authors_attributes, :title

  has_many :authors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
end
```

In a `before_create` callback, I want to check if another Publication exists with the same title and authors. The callback would look something like this:

```
def find_duplicate
  Publication.where(self.instance_values["attributes"].except("id", "created_at",
    "updated_at")).each do |publication|
      if publication.author_names.sort == @authors
        return publication
      end
  end
end
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to get `@authors`. I'm assuming I can somehow retrieve the params in a similar fashion to `self.instance_values["author_attributes"]`, but that's turning up as nil. How else might I access the params?

Comment: What are you expecting in @authors? The nested attributes from PARAMS?

Comment: Yes. There are particular attributes I want to pull from the Params, but first I need to get access to them. I've been toying around with `self.instance_values["associated_cache"], which does give me access to the next layer of nested params. However, there are other params more deeply nested than that which I can't get access to. Attributes like `publication[author_attributes][0][pen_name_attributes][name]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have 'authors' as an accessor that's built with the has_many.  So, instead of @authors, you would simply use 'authors' or 'self.authors' to get the (non persisted) author objects that are about to be created. Try something like:

```
Publication.where(self.instance_values["attributes"].except("id", "created_at",
    "updated_at")).each do |publication|
      if publication.authors.collect{|a| a.name}.sort == self.authors.collect{|a| a.name}.sort
        return publication
      end
  end
```

There are likely better more efficient ways to compare author names here, but this is the clearest way to explain and keep with your paradigm.

Comment: That does the trick! (And it's far more intuitive than I would have imagined, ironically enough.) Also, it turns out that I didn't even have to add `authors` to the attr_accessible list. Just calling `self.authors` works right out of the box.